# Certificate error when pulling docker images

Tags: ssl, docker, centos, certificate, docker-registry

When trying to pull a image from the docker hub, I am receiving some weird errors. The specific error that the docker daemon returns is:

> Error getting v2 registry: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/1:
>   x509: certificate signed by unknown authority

The weird thing is that running "docker search x" runs fine and returns what was expected. Also curling the page(`curl -vL registry-1.docker.io`) and running the openssl s_client(`openssl s_client -connect registry-1.docker.io:443`) doesn't return any certificate errors.

I am not behind a corporate proxy or anything like that. I've tried a lot of solutions like adding certs to the `/etc/docker/certs.d` directory, reinstalling the ca-certificates package, rebooting my machine, and almost everything that google searches suggested.

I am running CentOS version 6.8.

My docker version:

```
Client:
Version: 1.12.2
API version: 1.24
Go version: go1.6.3
Git commit: bb80604
Built: Tue Oct 11 17:00:50 2016
OS/Arch: linux/amd64

Server:
Version: 1.12.2
API version: 1.24
Go version: go1.6.3
Git commit: bb80604
Built: Tue Oct 11 17:00:50 2016
OS/Arch: linux/amd64
```

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried downgrading docker? This doesn't look like a problem in your machine. And this version is pretty new.

Comment: @CarlosRafaelRamirez I tried it with docker 1.8.0, but I recieved the same error.

Comment: Have you tried this -- https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/26468 ?

Comment: @AnandBhat Thank you for the link, I haven't it before but it didn't work either.